# How to find the derivative of $A=3x^2 (25-2x)^5$

Tags: derivatives

For $A=3x^2(25-2x)^5$, I need to show the steps on how to get the derivative. The derivative provided is $6x(25-2x)^4(25-7x)$.

The equation is formed from $A=3x^2y$ and $y=(25-2x)^5$ from a differentiation question.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Have you tried using the product rule?

Comment: Yes I but I don’t know how to go from there. I have got to 6x(25-2x)^5+(-10(25-2x)^4)x3x^2

Comment: ```The derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives``` and the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) can be used for derivative of a product

Comment: Thanks for showing your working; here's how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the terms to get the final answer:

$$6x(25-2x)^5-10(25-2x)^4 \cdot 3x^2$$
$$=6x \left((25-2x)^5 \right) - (25-2x)^4\cdot 30x^2$$
$$=6x \left((25-2x)^5 \right) - 6x \left( (25-2x)^4\cdot 5x \right)$$
$$=6x(25-2x)^4 \cdot(25-2x) - 6x(25-2x)^4 \cdot 5x$$

and now group the terms one more time to get to the answer.

Comment: Thank you I got now. I guess I was stuck on grouping the terms

Answer (score 1):

When you face products, quotients and powers, *logarithmic differentiation* use to make life easier
$$A=3x^2 (25-2x)^5\implies \log(A)=\log(3)+2\log(x)+5\log(25-2x)$$
$$\frac {A'}A=\frac 2x-\frac {10}{25-2x}=\frac {2(25-7x)}{x(25-2x)}$$
$$A' =A \times \frac {A'}A=3x^2(25-2x)^5 \frac {2(25-7x)}{x(25-2x)}=6 x(25-7 x) (25-2 x)^4 $$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. Find the derivative of $f(x) = 3x^2$ using the chain rule
2. Find the derivative of $g(x) = (25-2x)^5$ using the chain rule
3. Find the derivative of $f(x)g(x)$ using the product rule.